# Type safety of TypeScript Generic

Tags: typescript, generics, type-safety

I am not sure if I am doing it wrong, or if this is by design...

In my class

```
class List<T> { ... }
```

I have a method

```
public Add(value: T): void { ... }
```

I create an instance of my list

```
const fooList: List<foo> = new List<foo>();
```

but now I can still do

```
fooList.Add(new bar());
```

with foo and bar being unrelated types. This triggers no compiler warning, and I am a bit put off by that.

Am I doing it wrong, or is that as expected?

Comment: Are `foo` and `bar` actually *incompatible*? I get an error [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20List%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20add(value%3A%20T)%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fooList%20%3D%20new%20List%3CFoo%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AfooList.add(new%20Bar())%3B%0D%0A) as expected; please give an actual [mcve].

Comment: _Incompatible_, you say? Now this might explain a lot. They are in fact almost identical, bar has properties A: number, B: number and C: number while foo only has A and B.

Comment: Well then a `bar` is a perfectly reasonable thing to put in a `List<foo>`, as you can do anything with a `bar` that you'd be able to do with a `foo`; the *result* is type-safe, irrespective of whether the classes are actually related by inheritance.

Comment: Not where I come from. In C# / .NET, you can do that if the classes share an inheritance tree, explicitly defined, and that makes sense in my opinion. Just because classes share some property names I do not want them to be regarded exchangeable? Can I avoid that? I could give foo properties D (instead of A) and E (instead of B) and then they are different? That is ugly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe agreed, but it's till confusing to be able to add something in a List<Foo> for which the predicate `o instanceof Foo` is false.

Comment: It's not just *"share some property names"*, though - although you don't define it explicitly, `bar extends foo`, it has *every* property from `foo`. You may think it's ugly, but as far as I'm aware it's unavoidable in TS; that's the way the compiler (and it's *only* typed at compile-time, remember) determines whether it's OK.

Comment: Type compatibility in TypeScript is different from type compatibility in a language like C# or Java or many others. Type B doesn't need to extend type A to be of type A; it just needs to satisfy the interface of A. This is by design, as that's how it's supposed to work on the JavaScript ecosystem for a number of things, especially because type compatibility check is only available at compile time. Things like `instanceof` serve _some_ purpose but are better avoided altogether in TS, as is any attempt at reflection.

Comment: You want nominal typing but it is not supported yet https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing it wrong, or is that as expected?

If types are compatible then it will be allowed e.g.

```
class List<T> {
  add(val: T) { }
}

class Animal { name: string; }
class Cat extends Animal { meow() { } }

const animals = new List<Animal>();
animals.add(new Animal()); // Okay 
animals.add(new Cat()); // Okay 

const cats = new List<Cat>();
cats.add(new Animal()); // Error
```

## More

- Lookup TypeScript type compatability
- I wrote some docs as well : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-compatibility.html#generics